# My side drawer loses height when browser window height decrease

Tags: html, css, layout, sass, frontend

I have a project that supposes to look like this.

[image: app]

I wrote a collaspable side drawer for it, I set position to be absolute to document body, left 0, top is the top bar height. It is behaving how it supposed to untill I decrease the browser window height enough, and then it looks like this:

[image: issue]

I am not that good of a front end person, I tried to set the side drawer height to 100vh - topbar height, as well as 100% - topbar height, both no luck, did not solve the problem. If anyone could shed some light on this its greatly appreciated!

Here is the snippet of scss:

```
.control-panel {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: lighten($profile-cards-role-extra-light-grey, 45%);
  width: 30rem;
  left: 0;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 9.4rem);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(#000, 0.2);
  transition: margin, box-shadow, 0.3s ease-out;

  padding: 0 2rem;

  .toggler-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.8rem;
    top: 0.8rem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `vh` unit, which behaves relative to the window's height. So it will shrink too if the window does trying to maintain it's ratio.